# como seleccionar columnas columnas de dos en dos con pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un fichero con coordenadas, donde leftend se corresponde al inicio y rightend al final de la coordenada y quiero seleccionar las columnas de dos en dos, para luego iterar sobre las ellas. Como puedo hacelo con pandas?

```
seq0_leftend    seq1_rightend   seq2_rightend   seq2_leftend    seq3_leftend    seq3_rightend
1   109407  112030  1   1   112452
362514  364315  113882  105723  363106  364998
109408  362513  381662  107576  112453  363105
364450  504968  519575  355194  365030  507156
-504969 -515995 528317  487488  -507157 -518333
515996  671291  724500  496221  518334  675916
-671295 -682263 735077  689561  -676133 -687110
682264  707010  759456  700140  687111  711865
-707011 -709780 763157  721458  -711866 -714536
709781  934501  996929  721498  714537  943630
973791  1015417 1034492 947184  943632  985583
-961703 -973790 1040984 978602  -1067449    -1079534
948955  961702  -1061402    -986596 1054686 1067448
1015418 1069976 1125426 994605  985584  1040235
```

Comment: te refieres a algo como `df[['seq1_leftend', 'seq1_rightend']]` ?

Comment: Si, eso es  lo que quiero, @abulafia

Comment: Entonces el comentario ya ha respondido a la pregunta?

Comment: Realmente @abulafia , me gustaría hacer un bucle que las agrupe de dos en dos de forma automática ya que, tengo diferentes tablas con diferente numero de columnas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tenemos un dataframe como este:

[image]

Y que el número de columnas es par, para ir extrayéndolas de dos en dos una alternativa sencilla puede ser ir iterando por los enteros `i` = 0, 2, 4, ... y en cada iteración usar `df.iloc[]` para seleccionar las columnas entre `i` e `i+2` mediante un *slice*.

Por ejemplo:

```
for i in range(0, len(df.columns), 2):
  pareja = df.iloc[:,i:i+2]
  print(pareja.head(), "\n")
```

genera la salida:

```
   seq1_leftend  seq1_rightend
0             1         109407
1        362514         364315
2        109408         362513
3        364450         504968
4       -504969        -515995

   seq2_rightend  seq2_leftend
0         112030             1
1         113882        105723
2         381662        107576
3         519575        355194
4         528317        487488

   seq3_leftend  seq3_rightend
0             1         112452
1        363106         364998
2        112453         363105
3        365030         507156
4       -507157        -518333
```

### Notas

- Observa cómo en `range()` uso la sintaxis que me permite especificar el "paso" (2) para ir de dos en dos.
- Observa la sintaxis de `iloc[]` que tiene, separados por una coma, el rango de filas a seleccionar (en este caso `:` que significa "todas las filas") y el rango de columnas (en este caso `i:i+2` para seleccionar dos columnas contiguas que empiezan en el índice `i`)
- Si el número de columnas fuese impar la última iteración del bucle no dará error, pero devolverá un dataframe con una sola columna.
- Esto se puede generalizar fácilmente para agrupar de 3 en 3, o de N en N.

Comment: Una ultima pregunta @abulafia como puedo guardar el resultado del print como csv. Cuando lo hago, solo guarda el ultimo resultado del bucle. Los demás no aparecen

Comment: No está claro qué quieres hacer. ¿Generar un csv separado para cada pareja de columnas? ¿Concatenar todas las salidas en un solo csv? En el segundo caso ¿qué hacer con las cabeceras que aparecería intercaladas cada vez que se inicia una nueva serie de datos? ¿No importa que aparezcan? ¿Deberían no estar?

Comment: la idea @abulafia es concatenar todas las salidas en un solo csv y dejar que las cabeceras aparezcan intercaladas como en el print.

Comment: El problema es que si usas `df.to_csv()` dentro del bucle, cada iteración sobreescribe el mismo fichero producido en la iteración anterior. Tienes que pasar el parámetro `mode='a'` para que el csv sea abierto en modo "añadir". Pero en la primera iteración del bucle esa opción no debe estar (para que sea creado en ella). Pudes poner por ejemplo `mode='a' if i>0 else 'w'`